# Was the titan in the last episode of AOT S1 inside of the wall or on the other side? Also about walls origin

Tags: attack-on-titan

First, is the titan really inside of the wall like being trapped in it or just doing his/its job (lol)? I thought it was on the other side ever since because I have seen many comments/texts using the word "inside" which is very confusing.

Also it was said so far in the anime (currently S2 E6), that walls are (possibly?) made of titans' "crystals" making it pretty much indestructible, so doesn't that mean that titans aren't neccessarily inside of the walls since it would make the plot point a very funny one.

I am also confused as to how the walls are said to be "indestructible" like titans' crystals except certain parts like "entrances/exits", but some titans are seen to be able to pretty much destroy wall parts that are said to be indestructible like how (the collosal titan destroyed some parts of it) not sure if it really did though?

P.S. It's okay to spoil about the origin of the walls in your answers.

Comment: You really don't want us to spoil this question. My personal advice is to watch the second season, and read the manga. Everything will make sense then. :)

Comment: The thing is I don't want anything else except getting answers. Also, I have said in my question that it was said so far (S2 E6 meaning season 2 episode 6) so yeah, I'm updated in the anime. About the manga, I have read it, but stopped at vol 9, 10 or 11 not really sure because of how the author is milking and prolonging the story. I hate those kind of authors which also made me hate those kind of stories.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try and phrase your question so that it is not ambiguous.

Also, explaining this will be a major spoiler.

However, a few answers can be given.

> 1) Yes, that titan is inside the walls. 
>  
>  2) Yes, that titan created part of the wall with its hardened skin
>  
>  3) No, it is not trapped.
>  
>  4) The colossal titan can destroy a part of it, but not the whole wall.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58638/discussion-on-answer-by-surveycorps-was-the-titan-in-the-last-episode-of-aot-s1).

Answer (score 0):

Heavy spoilers into the manga.

> The walls are a collective mass of hardened titan skin. Deeper into the topic, The Wall Titans (壁の巨人 Kabe no Kyojin?) have the ability to harden not only their body, but a mass around itself as well. The walls have structure due to this. They can also fuse the mass together, creating the walls. The Wall Titans were Abnormal Titans similar in appearance to the Colossal Titan. They possessed the ability of crystallization and existed in vast numbers composing the three Walls. Manga spoilers: The Attack Titan (進撃の巨人 Shingeki no Kyojin) after having consumed The War Hammer and Founding Titans, was able to free the wall titans after Zeke and Eren made physical contact. In that moment Eren realized Zeke obtained the needed will as  as a descendant of the royal family to overcome his own will as the Founder's carrier.